# React Testing Error - Could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, frontend, react-testing-library

I am writing the test file for the following react file.

This is the react file

```
import Layout from 'components/Layout';
import Section from 'components/Section/section';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { ReactComponent as CrownIcon } from 'assets/images/crown.svg';
import { ReactComponent as LeaderboardLayout } from 'assets/images/leaderboard/leaderboard.svg';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useGetAnalyticsOverviewQuery } from 'app/services/home';
import Snackbar from 'components/Snackbar';
import { convertDate } from 'utils/utilities';
import * as microsoftTeams from '@microsoft/teams-js';
import { identify, track } from 'utils/segment';
import EmptyLeaderboardState from 'components/EmptyLeaderboardState';
import { useGetLeaderboardQuery } from 'app/services/leaderboard';
import Standings from './Standings';
import styles from './styles.module.scss';

let overview;
const Leaderboard = (props) => {
  const { isPublic, taskModule, workspace } = props;
  const { data: leaderboard = { lastUpdatedAt: '' } } = useGetLeaderboardQuery();

  if (!isPublic) {
    const { data, isFetching } = useGetAnalyticsOverviewQuery();
    if (!isFetching) {
      overview = data;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess();
  }, []);

  const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const neverUsedTrivia = !overview?.gamesPlayed;

  if (!userDetails.loading) {
    const { _id, loggedUsersCount = 0 } = userDetails;

    if (_id) {
      identify(_id, { 'Unique Logged In Users': loggedUsersCount });
      track('Visit Dashboard', {
        distinct_id: _id,
        Page: 'Leaderboard',
        Date: new Date(),
        'Unique Logged In Users': loggedUsersCount
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <Layout name='Leaderboard' isPublic={isPublic} data-testid='layout'>
      {isPublic && !taskModule && (
        <Snackbar
          text='You need to login to view your rankings'
          actionText='Login now'
          type='info'
          performAction={() => {
            window.location.href = `${
              window.location.pathname.includes('/tabs') ? '/tabs' : ''
            }/login`;
          }}
        />
      )}
      {!(overview && neverUsedTrivia && !isPublic) && (
        <div className={styles.title}>
          <CrownIcon />
          Leaderboard
        </div>
      )}
      <Section
        title=''
        noBorder
        style={{
          marginTop: 0,
          flexGrow: 1,
          marginBottom: '5rem',
          padding: neverUsedTrivia && !isPublic && '0',
          margin: neverUsedTrivia && !isPublic && '0'
        }}
      >
        {overview && neverUsedTrivia && !isPublic && (
          <div className={styles.neverUsed}>
            <EmptyLeaderboardState plan={userDetails.plan} teamId={userDetails?.user?.workspace} />
            <LeaderboardLayout width='100%' height='100%' />
          </div>
        )}

        {(!neverUsedTrivia || isPublic) && (
          <div className={styles.standingsWrapper}>
            {userDetails.plan === 'BASIC' && leaderboard.lastUpdatedAt && (
              <div className={styles.header}>
                <div className={styles.lastUpdatedDate}>
                  ⚠️ Your Leaderboard was last updated on ({convertDate(leaderboard.lastUpdatedAt)})
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
            <Standings plan={userDetails.plan} isPublic={isPublic} workspace={workspace} />
          </div>
        )}
      </Section>
    </Layout>
  );
};

Leaderboard.propTypes = {
  workspace: PropTypes.string,
  isPublic: PropTypes.bool,
  taskModule: PropTypes.bool
};

Leaderboard.defaultProps = {
  workspace: '',
  isPublic: false,
  taskModule: false
};

export default Leaderboard;
```

The test file is not even passing the basic test case.
Test File -

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import Leaderboard from 'pages/Leaderboard';


describe(`Leaderboard Component`, () => {
    it(`renders correctly`, () => {
        render(<Leaderboard />);
        expect(screen.getByTestId('layout')).toBeInTheDocument();
    })
})
```

I am getting this error in the terminal when I try to run the test file.
Error -
could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a

```
  19 | const Leaderboard = (props) => {                                                                                                      
  20 |   const { isPublic, taskModule, workspace } = props;                                                                                  
> 21 |   const { data: leaderboard = { lastUpdatedAt: '' } } = useGetLeaderboardQuery();                                                     
     |                                                                               ^
  22 |
  23 |   if (!isPublic) {
  24 |     const { data, isFetching } = useGetAnalyticsOverviewQuery();
```

I am not able to understand why this is not working. The main App.jsx is wrapped inside the .

Answer (score 0):

Given the error that you have provided, the issue is likely the custom hook `useGetLeaderboardQuery` consumes some kind of Redux context value (additional info needed from you), therefore causing the problem.

Since this is a unit test, you'd want to isolate the scope of this component unless you are writing an integration. Assuming the unit test is what we are writing, we can simply mock the `useGetLeaderboardQuery` to return the test data for different testing scenarios.

This can be achieved with the following code

```
import * as HomeService from 'app/services/home'

const mockHomeService = jest.spyOn(HomeService, 'useGetLeaderboardQuery')

describe(`Leaderboard Component`, () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        mockHomeService.mockReturnValue({
            data: { // adjust the data as needed
                leaderboard: { lastUpdatedAt: '' }, 
            },
        })
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks()
    })

    it(`renders correctly`, () => {
        render(<Leaderboard />)
        expect(screen.getByTestId('layout')).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
})
```

If you decide that you want to use different test data for your different test cases, feel free to do so in a similar fashion in the `beforeEach` block.